# I am building a beltsander racer and would like to know if I can put a starting capacitor on it?

Tags: capacitor

I am building a beltsander racer and I am using a 2 1/4 hp. Makita router motor. The motor has brushes and a commutator. The motor does not have soft start or variable speed. I would like to know if I can put a starting capacitor on the motor to get it to get off the starting line faster. Thanks. James.

Comment: what is the power source? (putting a capacitor on alternating current is a bad idea)

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oOQSt9K4gTY

Comment: https://www.instructables.com/Building-a-Belt-Sander-Drag-Racer-BSRA/

Comment: https://youtu.be/-UWDyvoAXDY?t=96

Comment: How do you expect the starting capacitor to work? This is a universal motor. It gives you the maximum torque from the get-go. It's up to your mechanicals to couple said torque the best to the track. Use something very grippy for the outer belt surface. The grippier the better.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 It's a universal motor, you'd have to hack it to even disconnect the stator from the rotor. What use would be capacitors?

Comment: Try this: put a piece of paper between the belt and the drag race surface. Now, the first revolution of the belt can pick up speed while it shoots the paper out the back. With the belt turning at speed, the belt will grip the racing surface and take off. Remember, this is just an experiment, but try it and let us know if there is a result.